# AWSのEC2インスタンスに配置したGoプロジェクトを定期的に実行したい

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

AWSのEC2インスタンス上に配置したGoプロジェクトを定期実行したいです。

具体的には

EC2インスタンスは常時起動させた状態で、毎週月曜の午後7時になったら

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$cd ~/go/src/my_project
[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$go run main.go
```

を自動で行いたいと考えております。(手動で実行した際に成功することは確認済みです。)

このような要求を実現するのに便利なAWSのサービス、および方法の提案がありましたらぜひご教授願いたいです。

**環境**

```
- EC2(無料枠)
  - t2.micro
  - Amazon Linux 2 AMI
  - MySQLの設定完了(RDSは使わない)
  - GOPATHは`~/go`に設定


- プロジェクトの構成
~/go/src/my_project
       |- main.go
       |- user.go
       |- targets.csv
       |- .env

- プロジェクトの概要
スクレーピングツールです。週1回だけ実行させたいと思っております。
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Systems Manager メンテナンスウィンドウ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-maintenance.html)で時間指定し、[AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html)でコマンドを実行するとかでしょうか。

（AWSのサービスを使わなくてもcronとかあるような気はしますが…）

Comment: 時間指定とRun Command の指定までできました！実行でエラーしていますので、また状況を追記させていただきます。